# New to JavaScript and needing to Return input back to the caller of the function.. Am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, function, return

This function should prompt the user to enter their name, balance, annual interest rate, and minimum payment interest rate. The function should return the resulting input back to the caller of the function. How do I know if I correctly returned it to the caller of the function? I'm new to JavaScript. I'm using pure JS with node and npm to view it in the terminal.

```
function getUserInput() {
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')({ sigint: true });
let name = prompt('Please enter your name: ');
let balance = prompt('Please enter your credit card balance: ');
let annualRate = prompt('Please enter your annual interest rate: ');
let minimumRate = prompt('Please enter your minimum payment interest rate: ');
return { name, balance, annualRate, minimumRate };
}
```

Comment: *Call it* and find out?

Comment: It looks fine, preferably use the require at the top of your script to avoid multiple calls. You can also declare all the variables as const since none of them are changing. To check if you are properly getting the values, you can console.log all the items after you make a call to this function, alternatively you can go to dev tools and debug your code from the sources section.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a console.log() call above the return statement:

`console.log(name, balance, annualRate, minimumRate)`

Comment: { name: 'Mitch', balance: '1500', annualRate: '18', minimumRate: '2' }

Answer (score 0):

Open your Developer Tools on Chrome, and type the values it returns, or call the method in the Console.
It may show errors if there are.